# how to run googlemap API V2 on 2.2 devices?

Tags: android

i found this tutorial http://android.develop123.com/index.php/component/content/article/2-android-42/4-google-maps-android-api-v2-tutorial  but my phone is android 2.2 how do i comppile this code in my 2.2 phone?/ i write this line
but when i run code is blast how do i compile this code in 2.2 device???

```
  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the google-support library to run Google Maps API V2 on this version of android. Take a look at this blog post I wrote on how to do that:

[Google Maps API V2 using support library](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Take importent notice at steps number 4 to add the support library:

> **4.** Another import we have to make in order to make our application work on
>   Operation system prior to API11 is to import the support library this can be done very easily
>   using Eclipse: Right-Click you project and choose “Android Tools” and then choose
>   “Add Support Library…”:

[image]

Comment: when i add gogleplay zervices lib is going to  red cross  X  what do i do??

Comment: what this line meaning in ur blog 

what you should do is to move the .jar file to a location where it’s path will be shorter
and then reference it again.

Comment: i did not understand this line

Comment: Me and some other users found that in some locations, where the path of the library is very long, there was a red cross on that referencing, so moving the library to another location like a folder inside one of your drives would solve this problem.